# html forms with c# code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I am trying to have a button when clicked it sends data to an sql server. I thought i could just create a form that would only have a submit button and I would handle that submit button in my home controller.

My html is as such:

```
<body>
<div  style="border: solid; max-width: 300px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">


    @using(Html.BeginForm())
    {

    <input type="submit" value="Vote"/>
    }

</div>



</body>
```

in my home controller i thought it was supposed to handle the form such as:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WAgermanClub.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{


[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult add(string vote1)
    {




        SqlConnection vote1connection = new SqlConnection("user id=userid;" +
                               "password=validpassword;server=o5z5dpwpzi.database.windows.net;" +
                               "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                               "database=wagermanclub_votes; " +
                               "connection timeout=30");
        try
        {
            vote1connection.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception g)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(g.ToString());
        }

        try
        {
            SqlDataReader myReader = null;
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from table", vote1connection);
            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {

                Console.WriteLine(myReader["Vote1"].ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
        }


        SqlCommand vote1command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table (Column1, Vote1) " +
                              "Values (1, 'Vote1' + 1)", vote1connection);


        vote1command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        try
        {
            vote1connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception h)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(h.ToString());
        }






    }
}
}
```

It all looks fine except for I get an error saying that in the add(string vote1) not all code paths return a value. What am I doing wrong? I do not have that great of a grip on html forms but I feel that once I get this it will lead to a better understanding.

All help appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: this doesn't have anything to do with your html.

Comment: As the error clearly states, your C# function needs to return a value.

Comment: @SLaks  could I have an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This;

```
public ActionResult add(string vote1)
```

Means you've declared a method that returns an ActionResult variable.
There is no return statement in your method. Once you fix this, the error will be gone.

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhhh, oh my I should have seen that. Thanks!